# Is the least significant bit (LSB) always the "first" bit?

Tags: c, bit

I'm reading [Modern C](http://icube-icps.unistra.fr/index.php/File:ModernC.pdf) (version *Feb 13, 2018.*) and on page 42 it says

[image: Image captured on page 42 of the book]

It says that the bit with index 4 is the least significant bit. Isn't the bit with index 0 should be the least significant bit? (Same question about MSB.)

Which is right? What's the correct terminology?

Comment: I believe authors meant least set bit, not least significant one.

Comment: When you write down 1000 then everybody assumes you meant 8 and not 1.  The MSB is on the left, like it is in decimal.  How you number them is however not standardized.  Most programmers use b3 for the MSB and b0 for the LSB, so the highest numbered bit is also the MSB, IBM does it the other way around.

Comment: @JensGustedt The easiest way to figure what the author meant is to ask him. This definition is indeed non-standard and somewhat misleading.

Comment: Well yeah, I wrote him an email not long ago. No reply as of yet, I didn't think about referring to him on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: My take is that the book simply tries to formally establish a `p` such as 32 on a 32 bit system, where `0xFFFFFFFF` would be the maximum value of an unsigned int and `0x7FFFFFFF` the maximum positive value of a signed int. Everything beyond that is quite uninteresting.

Comment: While the answers here are correct that these authors differ from common usage of LSB when discussing bits of integers, their terminology is not out of the blue. Outside of computing, when discussing ordinary decimal numerals, we say the last significant digit of “123.456000” is 6 because the trailing zeroes contribute no value, and the first and last significant digits of “000123000” are 1 and 3 because the leading zeros are unnecessary and the trailing zeros are merely placeholders. But this terminology applies for free-format numerals, not when there are a fixed number of digits or bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their definition of "most significant bit" and "least significant bit" is misleading:

```
8 bit Binary number : 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
      Bit number      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
                      |     |       |         
                      |     |       least significant bit
                      |     |
                      |     |
                      |     least significant bit that is 1  
                      |
                      most significant bit that is 1 and also just most significant bit
```

Comment: I'm accepting this, although all answers are acceptable, but this was the easiest to understand. Also "misleading" is the right word here.

Answer (score 3):

They're using an unusual definition of LSB and MSB, which only refers to the bits that are set to `1`. So in the case of `240`, the first `1` bit is b<sub>4</sub>, not b<sub>0</sub>, because b<sub>0</sub> through b<sub>3</sub> are all `0`.

I'm not sure why the book considers this definition of LSB/MSB to be useful. It's not generally interesting for integers, although it does come into play in floating point. Floating point numbers are scaled so integers above `1` have the low-order zero bits shifted away, and the exponent is incremented to make up for this (conversely, fractions have their high-order bits shifted away, and the exponent is decremented).

Answer (score 3):

The book's definition does not align with common/typical/mainstream/correct usage. See [Wikipedia, for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit):

> In computing, the least significant bit (LSB) is the bit position in a binary integer giving the units value, that is, determining whether the number is even or odd.

The book, on the other hand, seems to consider only bits that are 1, so that in an 8-bit byte representing the number 16, which we can write:

```
00010000
```

the bit that is 1 has index 4 (it's *b4* in the book's notation), and then it claims that that particular number's LSB is four.

The proper definition just uses LSB to denote that bit whose value is 1, i.e. the "units", and with that the LSB is the rightmost bit. This latter definition is more useful, and I really think the book is wrong.